# How do I make chrome tell a website it's visiting say it's internet explorer

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I want to make chrome tell a website the browser is not chrome, but IE 9 or 10. How is this done?

Comment: There is a Chrome extension for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is to change the user agent in Chrome.  To do this (latest version) you can do the following:

1. open the Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I on Windows/Linux, Command - Option - I on Mac OS X)
2. click the "settings" icon at the bottom of the window
3. click the overrides option
4. check "user agent" and select one of the options or select "other" and enter a custom user agent. You can find a list of agents at http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php